# How to parse xml response from soap of type base64binary in android?

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing, android-ksoap2

XML Response. 
Trying to get the value of `file` which is of type `base64binary`.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:xmds" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:GetFileResponse>
            <file xsi:type="xsd:base64Binary">/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAA=</file>
        </ns1:GetFileResponse>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Android code to fetch and parse above response. I m using below code to that.

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        String URL = "http://ngage.services/dss/albertsons/xmds.php?v=4&wsdl/GetFile";

        //for linear parameter
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME_GET_FILE);
        request.addProperty("serverKey", "nitro"); // adding method property here serially
        request.addProperty("hardwareKey", "01a5de64f888b0c5a286ff821695cdfd41ad08"); // adding method property here serially
        request.addProperty("fileId", "27");
        request.addProperty("fileType", "media");
        request.addProperty("chunkOffset", "0");
        request.addProperty("chunkSize", "207672");

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION_GET_FILE, envelope);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        SoapObject result;

        result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;

        if (result != null) {
            String encodedImage = result.getProperty("file").toString();
            Log.v("TAG", encodedImage);
            byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
            decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0,
                    decodedString.length);


        }
        return null;
    }
```

The encoded Image value should be `/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAA=` but I m getting its value as `base64Binary{}`.

Please help me out to parse it in right way

Comment: can you post your SOAP_ACTION_GET_FILE value

Comment: SAOP_ACTION_GET_FILE = urn:xmds#GetFile

Comment: I m not the getting the value inside <file> tag. Except that Getting complete response.

Comment: result.getProperty(0).toString(); try this

Comment: Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0):

Parameter which I was passing was misspelled. In place of chunkSize, it should be chuckSize.